# Augmented reality on Mobile platform - iOS

Tags: android, ios, camera

Is there a way that we can control the iOS device camera to an extent what colors it sees, what shapes it sees ? etc

I'm speaking about the ability to read information before the image is captured.

Consider my question as: Possibility of making an augmented reality game on iOS phones.

I dont find relevant help for my query in internet/iOS developer site. Hence posting here.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You can't really get any information before you capture an image. Apps like some photo apps, allowing you to focus the camera, preview images etc., constantly capture images and shows them, possibly in a lower resolution to make processing faster

Comment: I would like to capture colors from camera. Say, I ask user to show blue color. I need to capture the event when he shows this color to camera.

Comment: You need to clarify *how* you want to implement this before anyone can tell you if that's possible on iOS. Since AR is not strictly defined, you need to give us your definition of that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean you want your app to detect predetermined patterns using the camera, you will want to capture the result from the camera every few frames, and parse the image for near identical patterns.

If you want to save yourself the trouble of doing all the pattern matching you can use an AR library like the free and open source **[open frameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc)** or **[vuforia](https://developer.vuforia.com)**. It's very effective with the pattern matching, even at bizarre angles and on cylinders (bottles, cans...).

Here is an example of the tracking capacity of Vuforia.
[image]
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIBHNYxStmA

[Vuforia](https://developer.vuforia.com) is the only lib I have used. But [there are others](http://www.techygyaan.com/top-5-augmented-reality-sdk):

- [Wikitude](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/download-sdk/)
- [Metaio](http://www.metaio.com/products/sdk/)
- [String](http://www.poweredbystring.com)
- [IN2AR](http://www.in2ar.com/sdk.asp)

---

**Edit**:

- **[open frameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc)**. Before anything try it!  It's a surprisingly powerful library and free. Here is an example of [color tracking](https://sites.google.com/site/ofauckland/examples/10-testing).

Comment: Wow. This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot Coyote.

Comment: @Geeger Before settling on a lib I'd test it to see if fills your needs. If it's just about capturing given colours and shapes you might find a much simpler library. OpenFrameworks would be great for you I think.

Comment: @Geeger I edited my answer with a reference to very simple code for color tracking.

Comment: @Coyote Glad to read that you have experience using Vuforia in iOS, could you please have a quick look at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035046/how-to-calculate-the-camera-position-from-vuforia-gl-matrix